# How to create own events in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, events, callback

How should i create my own Events (This includes the code to bind the necessary callback) in c/C++ programming? It is directly available in Java.

Comment: What's available in java? C++ does not have a native concept of "events".

Comment: Please describe the exact feature in Java you are looking for. Ideally you would provide some example-code that illustrates what you want to achieve.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee2k0a7d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: It isn't at all clear what you actually want, but I'm going to suggest `std::function` anyway, and varius relatives like `mem_fn` and `bind`. They're not essential though; the Observer pattern, for example, only requires plain old abstract base classes defining the event function signatures. How about you give us an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't built-in events in C++, but if you don't want to reimplement your own classes, try [boost signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/signals.html).